# dnscrypt-proxy failed to start on 17.10

Tags: dnscrypt-proxy

I installed dnscrypt-proxy from the repo. I didn't touch any config.
Here's the error message

```
$ systemctl  status dnscrypt-proxy.service
● dnscrypt-proxy.service - DNSCrypt client proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ; 10s ago
     Docs: man:dnscrypt-proxy(8)
  Process: 20935 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy /etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20935 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

systemd[1]: dnscrypt-proxy.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: dnscrypt-proxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: dnscrypt-proxy.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped DNSCrypt client proxy.
systemd[1]: dnscrypt-proxy.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd[1]: Failed to start DNSCrypt client proxy.
systemd[1]: dnscrypt-proxy.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: dnscrypt-proxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy.service
[Unit]
Description=DNSCrypt client proxy
Documentation=man:dnscrypt-proxy(8)
Requires=dnscrypt-proxy.socket
After=network.target
Before=nss-lookup.target

[Install]
Also=dnscrypt-proxy.socket
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=notify
NonBlocking=true
User=_dnscrypt-proxy
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy /etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.conf
Restart=always
ProtectSystem=strict
ProtectHome=true
ProtectKernelModules=true
ProtectKernelTunables=true
ProtectControlGroups=true
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true
RestrictRealtime=true
```

<strike>Edit: OS restart somehow solve it.</strike>
<strike>Edit: Nope, after another restarts, issue comes back again. Tried systemctl restart and OS restart.</strike>

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue from `journalctl -xe`. I enabled the `BlockIPv6 yes` option which requires extra plugin. 
`sudo apt install dnscrypt-proxy-plugins` solved it.

Comment: BTW `block_ipv6 = true` is available without need to install extra plugins `at least Arch version` inside the file  `/etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.toml` .

Answer (score 0):

you have to leave 'listen_addresses = []' in /etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.toml empty and restart dnscrypt-proxy again.